# preg_match_all php inserting results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, preg-match-all

the below code searches a very long queried result, "body" and pulls out quoted numbers. I want to insert those numbers into a single column reference table. I had this working when it was a preg_match, but preg_match all has thrown a wrench in and it continues to bark about array-string conversion. Each "body" result can have multiple number results, and I believe this causing multiple arrays. Can anyone help me get this inserted?

```
$textToReplace = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT body from T1");
while($row2 = $textToReplace->fetch_array()){
    $body = $row2["body"];

    preg_match_all('#"\d+"#', $body, $matches);

    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $id=$match;
        var_dump($id);
        // $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into T2 VALUES($id)");
    }
}
```

This is a snippet of the result of a var_dump on $id:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '"10064905"' (length=10)    
array (size=3)
  0 => string '"10064788"' (length=10)     
  1 => string '"10064797"' (length=10)     
  2 => string '"10064807"' (length=10)
array (size=1)      
  0 => string '"10063833"' (length=10)       
array (size=1)       
  0 => string '"10063824"' (length=10)      
array (size=2)       
  0 => string '"10063805"' (length=10)      
  1 => string '"10063796"' (length=10)
```

Comment: `preg_match_all()` returns a 2-dimensional array. The first element is all the matches of the regexp, the remaining elements are the matches for each capture group in the regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_match_all()` returns a 2-dimensional array. By default, `$matches[0]` contains all the full-regexp matches, the remaining `$matches[n]` contain the matches for capture group `n`. In your program, you need to iterate over `$matches[0]`:

```
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $id=$match;
    var_dump($id);
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into T2 VALUES($id)");
}
```